# Python - Accept CLI arguments and process it

Tags: python, firebase

I created a python script to save some data to a test database in firebase. 
Here's my code:

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://www.somefirebaseapp.firebaseapp.com')

result = firebase.post('/data','test_data':'test123')
print(result)
```

It successfully inserted the data in the firebase console. Now I want to do this by running the python script via terminal (I'm using RPi), and add some arguments to save.

E.G

```
python3 firebase-save.py thisisatestdata
```

Which will make the code look like this:

```
result = firebase.post('/data','test_data':'inserted_argument_here')
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can do this using `argparse` or `click` library. https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import sys
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://www.somefirebaseapp.firebaseapp.com')

param_1= sys.argv[1] 

result = firebase.post('/data','test_data':param_1)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `click` (or build in `argparse`) library

```
from firebase import firebase
import click
import ast        

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://www.somefirebaseapp.firebaseapp.com')

@click.command()
@click.option('--data', default='', help='Test data.')
def test(data):
    try:
        test_data= ast.literal_eval(data)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    result = firebase.post('/data','test_data': test_data)
    print(result)
```